# How to display the pictograph emoji from a colon shortcode value?

Tags: javascript, github, emoji

I am working on formatting a response from the github api and commits sometimes use the colon type `:shortcode:` to display emoji, for example: `:bug:` =>

Does anyone know of a javaScript library or a method I can use to convert those shortcodes back to display the emoji... I guess convert them to unicode?

Comment: maybe this can help you https://docs.github.com/en/rest/emojis

Comment: Ahhh thank you!  I am dumb not looking for it in the API I am actually getting the data from hah.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment about the Github emoji api I was able to figure out something for this.  Here is my solution but I will keep this open for a little bit if anyone has any other ideas or improvements.

(I used local storage to not spam the API but I dont think that works in the SO sandbox)

https://jsfiddle.net/sushik/283hzubf/54/

```
async function run() {
await convertEmoji();

async function convertEmoji() {
  let testArray = [
    ':bug: fixed something',
    ':sparkle: cool new feature',
    ':feelsgood: :godmode: Much emoji',
  ];
  const container = document.getElementById('results');
  const localList = window.localStorage.getItem('emojilist');
  

  if(!localList){
  const url = 'https://api.github.com/emojis';
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const result = await response.json();
  window.localStorage.setItem('emojilist', JSON.stringify(result)); 
  }

let emos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("emojilist"));


// search for string by :shortcode: colons  

const reg = /:([a-zA-Z]+):/g;

  function replacer(match) {
  
    // remove the colons
    let emo = match.split(':').join('');
    let imgSrc = emos[emo];
    return '<img src="' + imgSrc + '" /> ';
    
  }

  testArray.forEach((commit) => {
   let formatted =   commit.replace(reg, replacer);
   container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', formatted);
    container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
 
  });
}
}
run();
```